I need to fill in a face b/w this circle and hexagon. But after selecting the vertex and pressing f, it's turns out like this(pic)

I'm trying to make a socket bolt, but after selecting the vertices and pressing f, it's filling the face in this weird way for some reason...

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

It is not clear from your photo, but it seems that you do not select all vertices. Give it a try pressing A then alt+f.


Hexagon and circle should be part of the same object, if not, join them (select both and press Strg+J).
Edit Mode; select all vertices by pressing A Mesh > Merge > By distance. This merges double vertices which might cause issues.
In edit mode, select hexagon and circle by pressing A and use Alt+F (rather than F alone) to fill the circle with the hexagonal hole.


What I can see looks like expected behavior: You only selected a small portion of the vertices on the edge of the bolt head, so pressing F connected the outer two and made a face from them all. Pressing F isn’t supposed to make faces with vertices that aren’t selected.
Something I’ll warn you of ahead of time, faces can’t have holes in them. If you’re trying to make a face with a hexagonal hole in it, it won’t work as is. You have to make two moon shaped faces and have them meet at the tips to get what looks like a face with a hole in it.
